# how can I bold some text in return statement?

Tags: java, android

[image: The image]

how can I bold some text written like  `return "Name: "+recName + "\n" + "Contact: " +recContact` 
I want to bold `Name` and `Contact`

Comment: Paste code not images!

Comment: In plain java when you output to console, you cannot add bold to a text. However if you are sending a java `String` to a webpage or to an android `TextView`, yes you can make it bold, see the answer below by @KJNewtown

Comment: sending a string to list view

Answer (score 2):

I see the Android tag, I guess you are trying to do that in 1 Texview?

When you return "Name: "+recName + "\n" + "Contact: " +recContact ", this is a String, you cannot bold a String, this is Data. You can only bold the widget you will use to show, such as a TextView.

Normally to do that you should use 4 textViews and set in the XML:

```
 android:textStyle"bold"
```

But there is another way in 1 TextView you can use Html:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "Name: " + "</b>" + recName + "<br>" + "<b>"  + "Contact: " + "</b>" + recContact);
```

**So just do That:**

//in your class you can return your data this way

```
return "<b>" + "Name: " + "</b>" + recName + "<br>" + "<b>"  + "Contact: " + "</b>" + recContact
```

//in your activity

```
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourVariable);
```

Comment: Ok, so just replace your:
return
with the one I provided, and use the reste of your initial code in your listView

Comment: return "<b>" + "Name: " + "</b>" + recName + "<br>"  
It doesn't help output displayed with bold tag

Comment: This should work. did you use Html.fromHtml(yourVariable) instead of youVariable in the listView Item ? If your do not Html.fromHtml . the tags will be shown as text

Comment: Html.fromHtml() where to add this? with return?

Comment: in your listView, apply it to the variable where you return your data

Comment: my list items came from database but in this return statement I want "Name" and "Contact" in Bold. 
Please write whole statement for bold and in which file I have to put that.